# Iterative PCA in C++

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, compression

I have a time-series data set (10,000 samples/sensors over ~2,000 time-series samples). I would like to keep the covariance structure in the data (sensor-sensor covariance) up to some error, while compressing this matrix into 10,000 samples over ~100 principal components (which can be interpreted as highest variance time series vectors).

I think iterative PCA would be the way to go. I wish, if possible, for the process to be O(sensors)*O((time-series samples)^x), i.e., to be linear in number of sensors.
What's the best way to perform this analysis to lead to the fewest number of PCs to capture a certain percentage of variance?
I'm working in C++

The bigger picture is that the process is online, where more time-series samples arrive and I wish to compress my data on the time-series dimension on-the-fly.